# programs to push files to remote computer

Tags: ssh, encryption, file-transfer, dropbox

#### Objective

Have a folder on my desktop, drop files into this folder, this begins a transfer from my computer to a remote computer. if the transfer is interrupted the transfer should resume from that point.

I have no need of "cloud storage", my objective is only to transfer the files.
I realize that a P2P transfer requires both machines to be online at the same time, but this is not a problem for my use.

I know command line solutions exist, but I'd prefer a drag and drop interface. I'd prefer a solution that includes end to end encryption.

#### Use case

I often wish to send large video files from my laptop to my home computer while traveling.

In my perfect solution, I'd simply drop those files into my "transfer to home computer" folder. This would begin the transfer. I could shutdown my laptop at any point (temporarily halting the transfer) and upon rebooting my laptop, the transfer would resume.

#### Ideas

- Dropbox
- ssh
- Teamviewer / vnc / rdp
- Wuala

While Teamviewer does contain a file transfer mechanism, but the Teamviewer window must remain open for the duration if the transfer is to succeed. Also, this method is not robust, no resume is possible after a disconnection.

Dropbox is not encrypted, and suffers from a storage cap.

ssh is commandline based, and I've found no gui interfaces that will achieve my objective.

wuala is encrypted, but I can't tell from their info if I can arrange so that the download begins automatically on my home computer.

Comment: This isn't the right place for this type of query, but take a look at cubby.com

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox does actually use encryption, it's just that it's their encryption key, not yours: https://www.dropbox.com/help/27/en

If you want to use your own key you can use a service like [Boxcryptor](https://www.boxcryptor.com/en/dropbox) or store all your files in a TrueCrypt container inside of your Dropbox account, which can be a little awkward:

- http://tonyonsecurity.com/2012/08/05/securing-your-data-on-dropbox-truecrypt/
- http://lifehacker.com/5794486/how-to-add-a-second-layer-of-encryption-to-dropbox

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer [BitTorrent Sync](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html) as it lets you share many folders between many Hosts (of course encrypted), and is able to concentrate the upload Bandwidth of hosts witch already have the file completely replicated localy.

It Provides you with a simple to use GUI, and has no problems with NAT

Bonus: It runs on Windows and Linux (FreeBSD hopefully soon :)